# Приведите пример реализации

Tags: android, android-studio

Подскажите мануал или пример реализации подобного:
На долгое нажатие какого-то view появляются верхний и нижний бары с функционалом (выделены красным).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сверху - ActionBar/Toolbar снизу Sneakbar. у view ставите setLongClickable(true) добавляете OnLongClickListener и в его коллбеке выводите на экран тулбар и снекбар

Answer (score 2):

Разделите задачу на 3 части:

1. Поймать долгое нажатие `View` - делается перехватом события `View.onLongClickListener()`, по которому вызывается появление верхнего и нижнего тулбаров.
2. Появление верхнего тулбара - например можно вызвать `AppBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true)`
3. Появление нижнего тулбара - делается через `Snackbar` (для этого верхнеуровневый лейаут должен быть обернут в `CoordinatorLayout`)

Соедините все 3 в одно и получите искомое.

Comment: Хм, допустим. Тогда теперь нужен пример того, как кастомизировать Snackbar чтоб он выглядел к примеру как на картинке

Comment: @Evgeny для кастомизации Snackbar можете сделать свой класс, отнаследовав его от [BaseTransientBottomBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BaseTransientBottomBar.html)

Comment: Буду пробовать. Благодарю за советы)

Comment: @Evgeny а еще ключ от квартиры где деньги лежат :)